# git push origin develop returns an error 408 The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, react-native, timeout

A clue could be that this is happening after to `upgrade React Native` to `0.59.x` in my case, `0.59.9`.

When I try to push my commits with `git push origin develop` I get an error and the push doesn't work.

Error:

```
$ git push origin develop

Counting objects: 46, done.

Delta compression using up to 4 threads.

Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.

Writing objects: 100% (46/46), 47.15 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.

Total 46 (delta 32), reused 0 (delta 0)

error: RPC failed; HTTP 408 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 408 Request Timeout

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Everything up-to-date
```

I've tried to fix it with commands like `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` and also I have checked that the remote origin is ok. I also have tried to disable ssl verify but I doesn't work neither.

This is git `diff --stat origin/develop_R develop_R` where develop_R have the changes I want to push and origin/develop_R is the branch that have to be update with my new commit when it would being pushed.

```
 android/app/build.gradle                                                                                  |  14 +--
 android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle                                                          | 790 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle.meta                                                     |   1 -
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/assets_error.png                                                   | Bin 720 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/assets_fotoperfil.jpeg                                             | Bin 2980 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/assets_ic_activacion.png                                           | Bin 7027 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/assets_ic_fichar.png                                               | Bin 3935 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/assets_ic_laycos.png                                               | Bin 13841 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/assets_ic_misdatos.png                                             | Bin 2852 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/assets_ic_misfichajes.png                                          | Bin 6456 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/assets_ic_misincidencias.png                                       | Bin 3588 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/assets_ic_missolicitudes.png                                       | Bin 1678 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/assets_logo_portal_horario.png                                     | Bin 12674 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/assets_logo_portal_horario_blanco.png                              | Bin 56445 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next.png        | Bin 216 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_previous.png    | Bin 214 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png         | Bin 134 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_certificado1.png                                            | Bin 16127 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_certificado2.png                                            | Bin 14383 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_certificado3.png                                            | Bin 16014 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_certificado4.png                                            | Bin 11483 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_certificado5.png                                            | Bin 11061 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_error.png                                                   | Bin 720 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_fotoperfil.jpeg                                             | Bin 2980 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_ic_activacion.png                                           | Bin 7027 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_ic_entrena1.png                                             | Bin 17593 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_ic_entrena2.png                                             | Bin 20830 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_ic_entrena3.png                                             | Bin 19798 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_ic_fichar.png                                               | Bin 3935 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_ic_laycos.png                                               | Bin 13841 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_ic_misdatos.png                                             | Bin 2852 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_ic_misfichajes.png                                          | Bin 6456 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_ic_misincidencias.png                                       | Bin 3588 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_ic_missolicitudes.png                                       | Bin 1678 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_logo_entrena_original_grande.png                            | Bin 13046 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_logo_gestion_horaria.png                                    | Bin 12894 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_logo_giho_blanco.png                                        | Bin 68998 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_logo_portal_horario.png                                     | Bin 12674 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_logo_portal_horario_blanco.png                              | Bin 56445 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_logo_sicho_blanco.png                                       | Bin 77235 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnativeelements_src_rating_images_bell.png        | Bin 2989 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnativeelements_src_rating_images_heart.png       | Bin 1928 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnativeelements_src_rating_images_rocket.png      | Bin 4050 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnativeelements_src_rating_images_star.png        | Bin 1961 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png         | Bin 100 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_error.png                                                  | Bin 720 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_fotoperfil.jpeg                                            | Bin 2980 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_ic_activacion.png                                          | Bin 7027 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_ic_fichar.png                                              | Bin 3935 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_ic_laycos.png                                              | Bin 13841 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_ic_misdatos.png                                            | Bin 2852 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_ic_misfichajes.png                                         | Bin 6456 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_ic_misincidencias.png                                      | Bin 3588 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_ic_missolicitudes.png                                      | Bin 1678 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_logo_portal_horario.png                                    | Bin 12674 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_logo_portal_horario_blanco.png                             | Bin 56445 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next.png       | Bin 232 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_previous.png   | Bin 239 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png        | Bin 134 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/assets_error.png                                                 | Bin 720 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/assets_fotoperfil.jpeg                                           | Bin 2980 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/assets_ic_activacion.png                                         | Bin 7027 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/assets_ic_fichar.png                                             | Bin 3935 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/assets_ic_laycos.png                                             | Bin 13841 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/assets_ic_misdatos.png                                           | Bin 2852 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/assets_ic_misfichajes.png                                        | Bin 6456 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/assets_ic_misincidencias.png                                     | Bin 3588 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/assets_ic_missolicitudes.png                                     | Bin 1678 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/assets_logo_portal_horario.png                                   | Bin 12674 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/assets_logo_portal_horario_blanco.png                            | Bin 56445 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next.png      | Bin 328 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_previous.png  | Bin 332 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png       | Bin 167 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/assets_error.png                                                | Bin 720 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/assets_fotoperfil.jpeg                                          | Bin 2980 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/assets_ic_activacion.png                                        | Bin 7027 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/assets_ic_fichar.png                                            | Bin 3935 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/assets_ic_laycos.png                                            | Bin 13841 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/assets_ic_misdatos.png                                          | Bin 2852 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/assets_ic_misfichajes.png                                       | Bin 6456 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/assets_ic_misincidencias.png                                    | Bin 3588 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/assets_ic_missolicitudes.png                                    | Bin 1678 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/assets_logo_portal_horario.png                                  | Bin 12674 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/assets_logo_portal_horario_blanco.png                           | Bin 56445 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_next.png     | Bin 388 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnativecalendars_src_calendar_img_previous.png | Bin 394 -> 0 bytes
 android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png      | Bin 207 -> 0 bytes
 ios/PortalHorario.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj                                                               |   1 +
 ios/PortalHorario/Info.plist                                                                              |   4 +-
 src/App.js                                                                                                |   1 +
 src/Constantes/constantesWS.js                                                                            |   2 +-
 src/Modulos/ListaFichajes.js                                                                              |  20 +++-
 src/Vistas/MisFichajes.js                                                                                 |   6 +
```

I understand that the left side is what remote have and then the right what I own in my local. It should be ok due to I deleted all that image files and all that changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a not react native related problem. You may have committed some **large files** when you were staging changes.
Please check staged changes. 
I think you should see **.HPROF file created by JVM (It's about 500 MB in size)** located under **android** folder of project when you were trying to make a release version of your app.

Comment: That .HPROF file doesn't exists. I'm trying to filter my project to see what could be sending with the git push command that could be so large but I just don't see anything weird. Almost I tried to push  the project having deleted android folder and the error persisted.

Comment: I almost have deleted ios folder and android folder, the error is happening anyway

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai When you have committed your changes you should use `git reset` in order to rollback before commit and then make changes. This does not make sense even if you delete something!

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai Provide status or send screenshot from it.

Comment: $ git status
On branch develop_R
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: But this is because I have been resetting my remote and creating new branchs to see what could happen, the original project (I have been playing with a copy to not corrupt the original) shows this :
$ git status
On branch develop_R
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop_R' by 6 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Use `git reflog` to see HEADS and then use `git reset COMMIT_ID` to reset to commit. Make sure to backup then use it.

Comment: But, I don't understand you, what do you want I do with it then?

Comment: Then delete large files after that commit them.

Comment: I have done, I don't know what could be but, there is not more longer files

Comment: Try to check your connection or initialize clean repository. Let me know if your problem was resolved.

Comment: I have checked the connection, it's ok (I can pull but not push and I can push other projects). I have tried initialize another repo and try to push all to it and the same error is showing. I'm really impressed due to I don't have info, I don't find info and the error is poor explained to try see what could happen. If the problem would be the size of any file it should alert you or something, I have a lot of files in my project and I'm scared that the only thing I could to "see if the problem could be solved" is check each individual file and going deleting and pushing in each iteration

Comment: That sounds weird!

Comment: I'm going to update the question with the git diff --stat origin/develop_R develop_R

Comment: Finally I could find a way to upload my files to a remote repo. I was no way to use my old repo, instead of that, I had to create a new Repo (which I tried to upload my old local git and it didn't work) and I had to remove my git files and upload all as new project. I'm not glad to see the result but at least I have safe my project again away from local corruption or accidents.

Thank you for the the focus dedication @Matin ZD

Comment: As I said you could this at first step. So happy that your problem is resolved :) Up vote if you want